# Chat tab not appearing on Microsoft Teams Browser version

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I have created an event for Micrsoft Teams via graph API. Sharing the list of steps below:

Create event method:

- I have created event.(online meeting)
- Event appeared on the Teams calendar
- Participant joined the call.
- Ended the meeting.

**Problem**: Chat Tab for the meeting is available for the desktop version with attendance report but the same chat tab could not be seen in web version. How do I get this right?
[Chat Tab in Desktop version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iefhq.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We tried this at our end, we cannot see meeting chat tab in both Web and Desktop. But we are able to see that meeting chat in mobile. We will check internally and get back to you.

Comment: We have raised a bug for the same, we will keep you posted on the updates. Thank you.